# how to convert np.double or np.float64 values to real value

Tags: python, numpy, file, binary

I have a binary file consists of multiple sensors data which is written by Catman software(HBM).
I am reading that file using guidelines given by Catman Software.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dZOw9L6_ukHNYlcR-n64DuRZ702nBq6jjA169q-aCz0/edit?usp=sharing

please check the link for the data writing format.
I am getting all the parameters correctly, but not the data, please help.

```
Actual sensor data showing in Catman software     
-0.05625    
-0.07083    
-0.07500    
-0.07396    
-0.07708    
-0.07188    
-0.06563    
-0.04896    

These are the values i got while reading same those values in double
-3.01998798238334e-13
1.68682055390325e-77
-1.07637219868070e-141
6.61923789516606e-206
-3.69718906070881e-270
-7.62423663153382e+282
4.68858598328491e+218
-2.61881942919867e+154

fid=open(file,"rb")
data = np.frombuffer(fid.read(8), dtype=np.double)
```

Please help me to get real values

https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6780-catman-file-importer?focused=54427cf8-d142-8e8a-812e-79e73b54b4fb&tab=function
MATLAB LINK FO REFERENCE

Answer (score 0):

this should read the first data value into a numpy array for you:

```py
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    file_id = int.from_bytes(f.read(2), byteorder='little')
    data_offset = int.from_bytes(f.read(4), byteorder='little')
    f.seek(data_offset, 0)
    first_data_value = np.frombuffer(f.read(8), dtype='<f8')
```

You will also need the number of channels and length of each channel from the channel info section to know how many 8-byte blocks to read.